# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data while starting the Application

Tags: android, metadata, android-syncadapter

I'm completely stuck here with this exception. This exception is completely slowing down the Application. And also I googled the Exception but no good results for me.

```
11-21 07:05:04.812: DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(75): volume aseced /mnt/sdcard/external_sd
11-21 07:05:04.816: DEBUG/MountService(135): getAsecVolumeState :: result = unmounted
11-21 07:05:04.816: WARN/ActivityManager(135): No content provider found for: 
11-21 07:05:04.851: WARN/ActivityManager(135): No content provider found for: 
11-21 07:05:04.855: DEBUG/PackageParser(135): Scanning package:    /data/app/vmdl70274207.tmp
11-21 07:05:04.863: INFO/PackageParser(135): com.nds.fr.activities: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
11-21 07:05:04.953: INFO/PackageManager(135): Removing non-system package:com.nds.fr.activities
11-21 07:05:04.953: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Force stopping package com.nds.fr.activities uid=10074
11-21 07:05:04.960: INFO/Process(135): Sending signal. PID: 1095 SIG: 9
11-21 07:05:04.972: INFO/Launcher(254): onResume(). mIsNewIntent : false
11-21 07:05:04.976: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 0
11-21 07:05:04.976: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 1
11-21 07:05:04.976: ERROR/Launcher(254): setWindowOpaque()
11-21 07:05:04.992: ERROR/WifiService(135): Multicaster binderDied
11-21 07:05:04.992: INFO/WindowManager(135): WIN DEATH: Window{40a77a98 com.nds.fr.activities/com.nds.fr.activities.MainTab paused=false}
11-21 07:05:04.996: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(135): high performance mode: false
11-21 07:05:05.023: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 2, mRestoring : false
11-21 07:05:05.023: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 3
11-21 07:05:05.023: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 4
11-21 07:05:05.023: ERROR/(254): onResume() check 5
11-21 07:05:05.027: INFO/Launcher(254): onResume() ended
11-21 07:05:05.031: INFO/Launcher(254): onWindowFocusChanged(true)
11-21 07:05:05.031: DEBUG/Launcher(254): It's image wallpaper. suggestDesiredDimensions(-1,-1)
11-21 07:05:05.089: ERROR/Launcher(254): setWindowOpaque()
11-21 07:05:05.097: DEBUG/PackageManager(135): Scanning package com.nds.fr.activities
11-21 07:05:05.101: INFO/PackageManager(135): Package com.nds.fr.activities codePath changed from /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-1.apk to /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
11-21 07:05:05.105: INFO/PackageManager(135): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk
11-21 07:05:05.117: WARN/InputManagerService(135): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1095 uid 10074
11-21 07:05:05.195: DEBUG/installd(85): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk' ---
 11-21 07:05:05.222: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1133): creating instr width table
 11-21 07:05:05.437: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1133): DexOpt: load 16ms, verify+opt 175ms
 11-21 07:05:05.492: DEBUG/installd(85): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk' (success) ---
 11-21 07:05:05.496: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Force stopping package com.nds.fr.activities uid=10074
 11-21 07:05:05.496: WARN/PackageManager(135): Code path for pkg : com.nds.fr.activities changing from /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-1.apk to /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk
 11-21 07:05:05.496: WARN/PackageManager(135): Resource path for pkg : com.nds.fr.activities changing from /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-1.apk to /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk
 11-21 07:05:05.500: DEBUG/PackageManager(135):   Activities: com.nds.fr.activities.StbDeviceList com.nds.fr.activities.Home com.nds.fr.activities.MainTab com.nds.fr.activities.TabGroup2Activity com.nds.fr.activities.GesturesActivity com.nds.fr.activities.GestureFunActivity com.nds.fr.activities.TabGroupActivity com.nds.fr.activities.ChannelListing com.nds.fr.activities.ChannelListEntry com.nds.fr.activities.TestAcc com.nds.fr.activities.EventListing com.nds.fr.activities.Channels com.nds.fr.activities.Volume com.nds.fr.activities.Remote com.nds.fr.activities.ExpandableList1 com.nds.fr.activities.EventDetails com.nds.fr.activities.CustomDialog com.nds.fr.activities.Boot
  11-21 07:05:05.574: INFO/installd(85): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk@classes.dex
  11-21 07:05:05.574: DEBUG/PackageManager(135): New package installed in /data/app/com.nds.fr.activities-2.apk
  11-21 07:05:05.628: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Force stopping package com.nds.fr.activities uid=10074
  11-21 07:05:05.679: DEBUG/dalvikvm(135): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1748K, 43% free 6246K/10887K, external 8804K/9907K, paused 50ms
  11-21 07:05:05.714: DEBUG/dalvikvm(254): GC_EXPLICIT freed 133K, 50% free 3174K/6343K, external 8594K/10637K, paused 34ms
  11-21 07:05:05.765: DEBUG/VoiceDialerReceiver(721): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.nds.fr.activities flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
  11-21 07:05:05.765: VERBOSE/RecognizerEngine(721): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): Package Name = com.nds.fr.activities
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): The package is being removed
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): IsPreload +
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): IsPreload -
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): The Package is not preload
  11-21 07:05:05.769: DEBUG/UNA(294): [PackageAgent] RemovePackageFromAStoreDB +
  11-21 07:05:05.785: DEBUG/UNA(294): [PackageAgent] RemovePackageFromAStoreDB -
  11-21 07:05:05.785: ERROR/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> Context is android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4051d9c0
  11-21 07:05:05.785: INFO/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> ==============================================
  11-21 07:05:05.785: INFO/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>     UinboxSevenReceiver() 
  11-21 07:05:05.785: INFO/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>     intent.getAction() :  android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
   11-21 07:05:05.785: INFO/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>   intent.getData() : com.nds.fr.activities
    11-21 07:05:05.785: INFO/UinboxLogger(729): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> ==============================================
   *11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{408a61e0 com.android.exchange.TasksSyncAdapterService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
   11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data
   11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.parseServiceInfo(RegisteredServicesCache.java:391)
   11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.generateServicesMap(RegisteredServicesCache.java:260)
   11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache$1.onReceive(RegisteredServicesCache.java:110)
   11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
  11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-21 07:05:05.792: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:641)
   11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{408a18c8 com.android.exchange.NotesSyncAdapterService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
 11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data
 11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.parseServiceInfo(RegisteredServicesCache.java:391)
   11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.generateServicesMap(RegisteredServicesCache.java:260)
 11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache$1.onReceive(RegisteredServicesCache.java:110)
   11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
   11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-21 07:05:05.796: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:641)
   11-21 07:05:05.812: DEBUG/dalvikvm(341): GC_EXPLICIT freed 171K, 51% free 2851K/5767K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 90ms
 11-21 07:05:05.828: DEBUG/Launcher.SWidgetPkgMgr(254): updatePackage=com.nds.fr.activities
  11-21 07:05:05.851: DEBUG/VoiceDialerReceiver(721): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.nds.fr.activities flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
   11-21 07:05:05.851: VERBOSE/RecognizerEngine(721): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
 11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{406d4930 com.android.exchange.TasksSyncAdapterService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data
     11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.parseServiceInfo(RegisteredServicesCache.java:391)
    11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.generateServicesMap(RegisteredServicesCache.java:260)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache$1.onReceive(RegisteredServicesCache.java:110)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  11-21 07:05:05.859: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:641)
  11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{406d44e8 com.android.exchange.NotesSyncAdapterService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data
  11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.parseServiceInfo(RegisteredServicesCache.java:391)
  11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.generateServicesMap(RegisteredServicesCache.java:260)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache$1.onReceive(RegisteredServicesCache.java:110)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   11-21 07:05:05.863: WARN/PackageManager(135):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:641)
   11-21 07:05:05.867: DEBUG/szipinf(135): Initializing inflate state
   11-21 07:05:05.988: DEBUG/vending(363): [38] LocalAssetCache.updateOnePackage(): No local info for com.nds.fr.activities
   11-21 07:05:06.210: DEBUG/dalvikvm(135): GC_EXPLICIT freed 487K, 44% free 6116K/10887K, external 6252K/7808K, paused 115ms*
   11-21 07:05:06.214: DEBUG/UNA(294): ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
   11-21 07:05:06.214: DEBUG/UNA(294): IsPreload +
   11-21 07:05:06.214: DEBUG/UNA(294): IsPreload -
   11-21 07:05:06.214: DEBUG/UNA(294): The Package is not preload
```

Comment: Check this question & answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505449/why-no-android-content-syncadapter-meta-data-registering-sync-adapter